# Unable to copy .ftpquota

Tags: ftp, file-access, filezilla

Trying to make a backup using FileZilla. All files copied but for `.ftpquota` got this error,

```
Command:    RETR .ftpquota
Response:   550 Can't open .ftpquota: Permission denied
Error:  Critical file transfer error
```

I have changed the access to `777` but still the problem is there. Any solutions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless you own your own company and are backing up one of your customers servers, you don't need .ftpquota copied in a backup.

Edit: Though to answer your question, I believe it's due to it being open in a program on the server. Probably the FTP server, try turning off your FTP quota on the server (if possible) and see if that makes a difference.